# Zend Framework 2 Quick Start with Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to get the ZF2 Quick Start to work with Doctrine. I thought I had it set up correctly but I'm getting the following error. Has anyone seen it?

> File:
>   /Users/jhicks/workspace/zf2-example/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:38
>   Message:
>   The class 'Album\Entity\Album' was not found in the chain configured namespaces ZfcUser\Entity, \Entity, ZfcUserDoctrineORM\Entity

Here is my Doctrine config:

```
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                )
            )
        ),
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host'     => 'localhost',
                    'port'     => '3306',
                    'dbname'   => 'zf2example',
                    'user'     => 'user',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ),  
            )
        )
    ),
);
```

Comment: Your config File got the appropriate Namespace? And this is your `module.config.php` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look closely at the list of entity namespaces in the exception message...

```
ZfcUser\Entity, \Entity, ZfcUserDoctrineORM\Entity
-------------------^
```

You will notice that one of them is just `\Entity`.  This is due to the fact that you've configured your entity namespace in a PHP configuration file somewhere (ie: either a file in `config/autoload` or your module's `config/module.config.php` file), and by default those files don't have a namespace.  Try adding one to the top of the configuration file:

```
<?php
namespace Album;
```

In my local tests this fixed the issue.